# SQL: Where IN combined with AND

Tags: sql

The following query results in a set containing 1 product for each order, even if a particular order has multiple products.

```
select orders. *, products. *
from `orders`
inner join `products`
where orders.customer_id = " . $customer_id . "
  and orders.order_processed > 0
  and products.product_id in (orders.products)
```

(orders.products being a string like 69,74,35,21).

I tried rewriting many times, but failed to get the desired result. 
Who could point me in the right direction? Thanks for your support.

Comment: What rdbms do you use? Your `inner join` is missing an `on` statement. Between the parentheses of an `in` should be either hard coded values or an `select` statement.

Comment: Fix your data structure.  You need an `OrderProducts` table.  A comma-delimited list is the wrong way to store that list.

Comment: put a select statement within the `in` brackets, if your inner joining on the orders table and products table using a common ID then it will only bring values that exist in both anyway

Comment: Thanks for your useful comments. I will revise the data structure and then rewrite the query.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: While you are rewriting, see whether you can use parameters to pass values instead of using string concatenation, to prevent *sql injection*.

Answer (score 0):

You have used IN operator in sql query. It matches given expression with any matching value in the "result set". Try using a subquery to fetch the result set for products.product_id in(orders.products)

Answer (score 0):

Your use of IN() probably does not achieve what you are hoping for. Your query might look more like  this (a guess)

```
select orders. *, products. *
from `orders`
inner join `products` ON orders.product_ID = products.id
WHERE orders.customer_id = " . $customer_id . "
  and orders.order_processed > 0
```